# Linux: count unique values in specific field and rewrite line

Tags: awk, sed

I'm getting output from an specific application in the following format:

```
47114   test RUN   test_medium_ciara fea-admin ciara08:ciara08:ciara08:ciara08:ciara08:ciara08:ciara08:ciara08:ciara02:ciara02:ciara02:ciara02:ciara02:ciara02:ciara02:ciara02 rw         01/10-11:12:23 default    000:30:54.00 11162  0      24133,24134,24136,24177,24248,248
```

And I want to count the unique values from the 6th field:

```
ciara08:ciara08:...
```

Example output

```
47114   test RUN   test_medium_ciara fea-admin  2  rw         01/10-11:12:23 default    000:30:54.00 11162  0      24133,24134,24136,24177,24248,248
```

EDIT:

```
47117   test  RUN   abaqus_medium fea-admin   r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09 mox        01/10-11:37:10 default    008:17:45.00 18025  21239  78836,78840,78842,78852,78880,78935,78938,78951,78939,78940,78941,78942
47123   test  RUN   abaqus_medium fea-admin   r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n10:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n06:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07:r50n07 td42       01/10-12:09:47 default    000:00:01.00 61     607    181931,181935,181937,181945,181975,181982 01/10-12:09:49 -
47117   test  RUN   abaqus_medium fea-admin   r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n12:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n01:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n08:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09:r50n09 mox        01/10-11:37:10 default    008:17:45.00 18025  21239  78836,78840,78842,78852,78880,78935,78938,78951,78939,78940,78941,78942
```

OUTPUT with @RavinderSingh13 script:

```
$ awk '{num=split($6, A,":");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){B[A[i]]};$6=length(B);print}' test.txt
47117 test RUN abaqus_medium fea-admin 4 mox 01/10-11:37:10 default 008:17:45.00 18025 21239 78836,78840,78842,78852,78880,78935,78938,78951,78939,78940,78941,78942
47123 test RUN abaqus_medium fea-admin 7 td42 01/10-12:09:47 default 000:00:01.00 61 607 181931,181935,181937,181945,181975,181982 01/10-12:09:49 -
47117 test RUN abaqus_medium fea-admin 7 mox 01/10-11:37:10 default 008:17:45.00 18025 21239 78836,78840,78842,78852,78880,78935,78938,78951,78939,78940,78941,78942
```

I would bet on sed or awk but I'm a bit puzzled

Comment: What does `I would bet on sed or awk but I'm a bit puzzled` mean? Does the script not do what you want? Do you have a question?

Comment: @Ed Morton, my question is answered. I knew I should use sed or awk for this problem and it's solved with awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say:

```
awk '{num=split($6, A,":");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){B[A[i]]};$6=length(B);print}'   Input_file
```

With the following it will not keep on adding the length of array B (thanks to OP for mentioning it).

```
awk '{num=split($6, A,":");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){B[A[i]]};$6=length(B);delete(B);print}'   Input_file
```

Comment: why `!B[A[i]]++` ? why not just `B[A[i]]` ?

Comment: Thanks @AkshayHegde, have changed it to that now.

Comment: Your script kinda works. For the first instances. But after a few it starts to add the value to the value of the previous line. Can't figure why.

Comment: Thank you Bart for letting me know, yes it will do as array's length is keep on increasing, could you please try following 

awk '{num=split($6, A,":");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){B[A[i]]};$6=length(B);delete(B);print}'   input_file

Comment: `num=split($6, A,":");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){B[A[i]]};` can be reduced to just the following: `split($6,A,/:/);for(i in A)B[A[i]];`. I would recommend not using all-upper-case variable names, btw, to avoid clashes with builtin names.